# How to use logical or in Python ortools

Tags: python, constraints, or-tools, cp-sat

The objective is to constrain some of the variables to be assigned only to a specific value.

Assume there are 4 variables, but var x3 only can be assigned to 1 and 4. Formally,  `x[3] ∈ {1,4}`

I tried using the `OnlyEnforceIf` as below, however, it does not produced the intended result.

May I know how to resolve this issue?

```
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model
model = cp_model.CpModel()
x = [model.NewIntVar(0, 10, f'val_{i}') for i in range(4)]
b = [model.NewBoolVar(f'b{i}') for i in range(4)]
model.AddExactlyOne(b)
for idx in range(4):
    if idx == 3:

        for hval in [1,4]:

            model.Add(x[idx] == hval).OnlyEnforceIf(b[idx])
            model.Add(x[idx] != hval).OnlyEnforceIf(b[idx].Not())
solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
status = solver.Solve(model)

if status == cp_model.OPTIMAL or status == cp_model.FEASIBLE:
    for n,dval in  enumerate(x):
        print(f'int: {n}: sol: {solver.Value(dval)}')
else:
    print('unsat')
```

Which produce

```
int: 0: sol: 0
int: 1: sol: 0
int: 2: sol: 0
int: 3: sol: 0
```

However, I expect the possible(s) output to be (not limited to) as below

```
int: 0: sol: 0
int: 1: sol: 0
int: 2: sol: 0
int: 3: sol: 1
```

or

```
int: 0: sol: 8
int: 1: sol: 8
int: 2: sol: 0
int: 3: sol: 4
```

Comment: why do you say: `but var x3 only can be assigned to x[3] ∈ {1,4}`. The solver will assign values to all variables.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I had updated the post to make things much more clearer

Comment: What is the issue ?

Comment: Hi @LaurentPerron,  the solver did not produce what I intend it to produce I attached two expected solutions on the OP. I think I make some mistakes when setting the `OnlyEnforeIf`.

Comment: does not tell me what is the issue. Please show the wrong output.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you forgot to add that one of the bi must be true.

```
model.AddExactlyOne(b)
```

Otherwise, the solver will happily set them all to false.
You are also using the wrong index in the `OnlyEnforceIf` part.
You are not constraining all bi and all hval (using [] instead of range)

the full code should be:

```
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model

model = cp_model.CpModel()

x = [model.NewIntVar(0, 10, f'x_{i}') for i in range(4)]
b = [model.NewBoolVar(f'b_{i}') for i in range(4)]

# Exactly one of the b[i] must be true.
model.AddExactlyOne(b)

for idx in range(4):
    if idx == 3:
        for hval in range(4):
            model.Add(x[idx] == hval + 1).OnlyEnforceIf(b[hval])
            model.Add(x[idx] != hval + 1).OnlyEnforceIf(b[hval].Not())

solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
status = solver.Solve(model)

if status == cp_model.OPTIMAL or status == cp_model.FEASIBLE:
    for dvar in x:
        print(f'{dvar.Name()}: {solver.Value(dvar)}')
    for bvar in b:
        print(f'{bvar.Name()}: {solver.BooleanValue(bvar)}')

else:
    print('unsat')
```

Now correctly prints

```
x_0: 0
x_1: 0
x_2: 0
x_3: 4
b_0: False
b_1: False
b_2: False
b_3: True
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, IIUC, the `AddExactlyOne`  should be before the `Add()` operation. However, now the solver indicates there is no solution for the edited constraint, which I not expect. May I know where exactly should the `model.AddExactlyOne()` should reside? Appreciate for the advice @Laurent

Comment: Somewhere where it is added only once. And addexactlyone(b), not addexactlyone(b[idx])

Comment: Hi @Laurent, I did as suggested but the changes still produced an undesired result. Specifically, it returns `int: 0: sol: 0
int: 1: sol: 0
int: 2: sol: 0
int: 3: sol: 0`

Comment: python array are 0 valued. And you should use hval instead of idx in the OnlyEnforceIf.

Comment: Thanks for entertaining this issue, however the changes you made still does not yield the expected output. Specifically, the solver is expected to output the  `int: 3:` to be either  `sol: 1` or `sol: 4`

Comment: fixed. one more bug in your code.

Comment: Hi @Laurent, thanks for the time and idea, but your proposal seems to work only for x[3] ∈ {4} and will break if I change the constraint say,x[3] ∈ {1,5,8}.

Comment: Just adapt the code. Have an array of values. Create the b based on the length of this array. Use values[i] instead of hval + 1. Please, this is no longer an or-tools question, but a python one.